# Haskell JSON Parser Improvements

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, functional-programming

For one of my courses last semester we were tasked with implementing a JSON parser that spits out formatted HTML. I ended up implementing it in what I felt was more of an iterative fashion than a functional one. Here's the main code snippet I have issues with:

```
stringToTokens (x:xs)
            .....
            | x == '\"' = StringLiteral (parseStringToken xs) : stringToTokens (advancePastString xs)
            | startsNumeric x = Numeric (processNumeric (x:xs) takeWhile) : stringToTokens (processNumeric xs dropWhile)
            | startsKeyword x = Keyword (processKeyword (x:xs) take) : stringToTokens (processKeyword (x:xs) drop)
            .....
            | otherwise = stringToTokens xs

....
advancePastString :: String -> String
advancePastString (x:xs)
            | x == '\"' = xs
            | x == '\\' = advancePastString (tail xs)
            | otherwise = advancePastString xs
```

My issue with how I went about handling this is that it feels as if I've taken how I would implement it in a procedural language and just replaced the loop with recursion and drop functions. While this does work I'm wondering what would be a more idiomatic functional way of handling this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would belong better on The Code Review SE https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Well usually people do not write tokenizers themselve: they use what is known as *compiler compilers*, programs that turn a list of regexes or a context free grammar into a lexer/parser.

Comment: @EliSadoff: although I agree, there is only a very limited number of Haskell programmers active on cr.SE, so usually people do not get much help there.

Comment: @EliSadoff It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SamOnela Thank you. Sorry I hadn't seen that post before.

Comment: FWIW, I think this is a fine, on-topic question, with a clear answer. There are (just) two idiomatic Haskell solutions: parser combinators (which by and large share the bulk of their API -- enough that I could write some code for the two parser chunks mentioned above in a pretty much library-agnostic way) and parser generators. I'd love to write this answer, except that I've never used parser generators, and don't feel qualified to write that half of the answer. If somebody will volunteer to do that half, I'll happily start (or contribute to) a community wiki answer on the combinator half.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem With all due respect, whether there are Haskell answerers on CodeReview has no bearing at all on whether the question is on-topic here. I do think it's on-topic here; but that's because I think it is about a specific programming problem that Haskell experts can agree on the answer to, not because there's some other site elsewhere that it wouldn't get answered on. (And Sam Onela has already represented the obvious analog of this discussion in the other direction: just because the question would fit well on CodeReview has absolutely no bearing on whether it's off-topic here.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for mentioning the parser combinators, and parser generators. Even without giving any example code it gives me a place to look to see how this could be tackled in a more functional way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try a parser combinator. This is a good place to start: [Write You a Haskell: Parsing by Stephen Diehl](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/002_parsers.html). It gives you a simple example of what a parser combinator looks like. Then I would look at the available parser combinators like `parsec`, `attoparsec` and `trifecta`. I personally like `attoparsec`, but `trifecta` has a lot more features.

I've also written a small tutorial on `attoparsec`. It isn't complete but it should help you get started.

- [Attoparsec Tutorial Part 1 - Parser Combinators and Test Driven Parsing](http://mchaver.com/posts/2016-05-09-attoparsec-tutorial-1.html)
- [Attoparsec Tutorial Part 2 - Parse and Return Values](http://mchaver.com/posts/2016-05-09-attoparsec-tutorial-2.html)
- [Attoparsec Tutorial Part 3 - Parse Data in Variable Order](http://mchaver.com/posts/2016-05-10-attoparsec-tutorial-3.html)